# SCCM client: install SoftwareCenter available packages via commandline

Tags: windows, powershell, sccm

I was wondering if there was a way to have a script in PS which installs multiple packages in order from the Software Center. This would be helpful for some customers where base software is required after staging but no changes to the deployment task-sequence are allowed.

The scripts should be ran on the client themselves.

Any help/tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Within SCCM package model you can specify that the packages are "Mandatory". This will install them without the user needing to interact with Software Center. If you are just running a script, you can specify this in the package command line to leverage this functionality.

To deal with the order in which they are deployed, you can specify package install pre-requisites, forcing one script to run before another.

I am not aware of any client Powershell actions that can be performed to interact with Software Center.